# ¿Qué es una "cocatriz"?

Tags: palabras-raras, animales

En el Cancionero de Pero Guillén (1492) encuentro estos versos:

> Debaxo de la cerbiz,
> en una saleta nueba
> que sale sobre la cueba
> do cría la **cocatriz**,
> un Obispo muy honrrado ...

No aparece en el Diccionario de la Lengua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No aparece en el Diccionario, pero [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocatriz) tiene un artículo sobre eso:

> La **cocatriz** es una bestia mítica, esencialmente una criatura bípeda con apariencia de dragón o serpiente, con cabeza de gallo. Descrita por Laurence Breiner como "un ornamento en el drama y la poesía Isabelinas", ha estado presente prominentemente en el pensamiento y los mitos ingleses por siglos. Este autor refirió que "La cocatriz, que nadie vio, nació por accidente a finales del siglo XVI y murió a la mitad del siglo XVII, una víctima de la nueva ciencia".

Pero lee por favor la respuesta de @j''; es mejor en explicar el uso en un poema del siglo XV.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct - this appears to be a translation of the respective English Wikipedia entry, but in the 15th century *cocatriz* was used in Spanish as a synonym for *cocodrilo*. It was only later *cocatriz* adopted the English/heraldric meaning as a calque of "cockatrice" (after the original *cocodrilo* sense had fallen out of use).

Comment: @j'' Esta bien, solo copié lo que encontré ...

Answer (score 2):

Historically *cocatriz* was used in Spanish to refer to **the Nile crocodile**. The earliest recorded use of it in this context appears to be from Alfonso X:

> En el Nilo á una bestia que llaman **cocadriz**.

- *General Estoria. Primera parte* (c.1275)

> E la otra que esta dell otro cabo del Rey a la mano derecha es a semeiança de la **cocatriz** que es bestia & pescado. & esta es fecha como lagarto. & cria en las aguas dulçes & sennaladamientre en el grant rio que llaman nilo.

- *Libro de ajedrez, dados y tablas* (1283)

Similar descriptions occur in later centuries:

> Et en todas cosas el rio de Nill puede seyer loado sobre todos los otros, sino que tiene vna manera de bestias qui son como dragones, et comen ombres et cauallos dentro de la agua et en la ribera, quando los conssiguen; et aquellas bestias han nombre **cocatrix**.

- *Flor de las ystorias de Orient. Bibl. Escorial Z.I.2* (c.1377)

> Ay en esta rivera unas bestias que se crian dentro del agua, que llaman **cocatriz**, las quales, quando están en el agua, non ay ome ni bestia que puedan alcançar que non la matan, é dizen que fuyen en el agua del búfano, é por esto, como en todas aquellas partes non ay puente nin se podríe fazer por las grandes arenas, é para aver de pasar de la una parte á la otra, la pobre gente avría menester de alquilar barco, suben en aquellos búfanos é pasan seguros el rio á nado sin peligro ninguno.

- *Andanças e viajes* (1457)

And this is the meaning with which it (briefly) entered Spanish dictionaries, parallel to the mythical use in English (cf "cockatrice"):<sup>1</sup>

| Year | Dictionary | Entry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1729 | *RAE* | COCATRIZ.f.f. Serpiente que se cria en el Nilo, lo mismo que Crocodilo. Trahe esta voz nebrixa en su Vocubulario.Lat.*Crocodilus.* |
| 1846 | *Salvá* | COCATRIZ. f. **ant.** <sub>COCODRILO.</sub> |

---

**Notes:**

1. The mythical sense [comes from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockatrice#Origins) a translation of the mythical *basilisk* (basiliscus) as *cockatrice* in a 14th century English translation of *De proprietatibus rerum*.

   Note in a contemporary Spanish translation of *"Historia de Jerusalem abreviada"*, the translator uses *cocatriz* to describe what is later translated as [crocodilis](https://archive.org/details/IacobiDeVitriacoCardinalisLibriDuo1596/page/n239/mode/2up?q=crocodilis).